# How can I get metadata from a http stream in Java?

Tags: java, android, streaming, metadata, http-streaming

Suppose I am receiving audio stream for example from the following urls :

1. [IdobiRadio "http://83.133.126.34:80"](http://83.133.126.4:80)
2. [Cool93 Fahrenheit "http://203.150.224.142:8000"](http://203.150.224.142:8000)

How can I get meta information like Song title, artist name etc using Java or Android.

Comment: this looks like what you want http://uniqueculture.net/2010/11/stream-metadata-plain-java/ but i have not go into detail.

Comment: @Jasonw. Thnx. It really does. I would check and let u know.

Comment: @jasnow it is not working in Java. Getting error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at IcyStreamMeta.getArtist(IcyStreamMeta.java:36)
 at MetaTest.main(MetaTest.java:21)
"

Comment: I think that error message, "String index out of range: -1 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)" is very obvious, you wanna spend more time to look into this line (by println before substring?), String title = streamTitle.substring(0, streamTitle.indexOf("-"));

Comment: Imon, got rid of the hurdles?

Comment: Thanks for asking Jasnow. Yes, I have found the problem. It happens when there is nothing or there is no "-" character in streamTitle. I have tested with many urls and it seems there is no standard for broadcasting metadata through the urls. Everybody is following their own style and many does not supply at all. I wonder if there is a better way to do that.------ Thank you again.